# Jquery menu not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

HI I have this jquery menu here

http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/8/

and it doesnt seem to work ..... The button is supposed to expand to right on hover

Thanks all efforts appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to your css:

```
.anim_queue_example1 a
{

    margin: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 25px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;

    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;

    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    position:relative;

}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/pJMva/10/

Comment: Hey Niklas so that was the only problem 



position:relative;



thanks a lot I realy appreaciate it I wish i could upvote more than once ...

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.anim_queue_example1 a')
    .hover(function() {
          $(this).animate({
              opacity: 0.25,
              left: '+=20',
              height: 'toggle'
          }, 5000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
          });
     }, function() {
          $(this).animate({
          opacity: 0.25,
          left: '+=0',
          height: 'toggle'
          }, 5000, function() {
             // Animation complete.
        });
    });

});
```

Check the working example here  http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/23/